# Calculation with external data from .txt defined as variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab

I used to analyse my data in Matlab and try to switch to LaTeX right now.
So basically I have trouble with the translation `matlab-latex`.

This table is my data from `mydata.txt`:

```
f 1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

2 3 4 5 6

3 4 5 6 7
```

The first thing I want to do is to ascribe variables to the columns and use them in an equation. The code below is not working, but maybe it's helpful to show what I'm trying to do... maybe.

**Step 1:**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\begin{document}`

`\FPset\myX{\thisrow{f},{mydata.txt}}
\FPset\myY{\thisrow{1},{mydata.txt}}
\FPset\myZ{\thisrow{2},{mydata.txt}}
\FPeval\result1{\sqrt{(\myY ^2 + \myX ^2) * \myZ}}
\end{document}
```

This is the code I use in Matlab: `result1=sqrt(myX.^2+myY.^2).*myZ`

I just change the name of the columns to the same ones as in the LaTeX example.

In Matlab I "have" (I'm sure there is a better solution) to import the variables  `(\myX,...,\myY)` one by one as column vectors.

**Step 2:**

After the first step I want to use `result1` in an other equation. Can I handle `result1` like a variable after that?

**Step 3:**

Last but not least my goal is to plot two columns, so for example `\myX` against `\myY`.

Matlab: `plot(myX,myY)`

LaTeX:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot table [x= \myX ,y= \myY]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

ps: As you can see I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so if you could give me a link for an overview of operators like "sum", "sqrt"... I would be thankful! I need it for this Bad boy (matlab: `X=sqrt(sum(Y(:,1:4).^2, 2)).*Z`

Comment: Probably easier to do all calculations in Matlab and export a CSV-file of the results that you can then plot in `pgfplots`, or have a look at `matlab2tikz` that generates `pgfplots` code for you.